# Radio tray icon applet does not load in Unity

Tags: unity, 11.04

The Radio Tray icon will not show in Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) Beta 2 under Unity, but it works in classic mode.

I have it set as a startup application using the command `/usr/bin/radiotray`. It loads perfectly in classic mode, but not at all in Unity.

How can I get Radio Tray to work when I use Unity?

Comment: This is [bug 717777](http://pad.lv/717777).

Answer (score 7):

The latest version from [sourceforge](http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/) (at the time of writing this, it is version 0.6.4) now has both app-indicator support (for Natty) and notification area support (for other ubuntu variants and versions before 11.04).

Install the application via

```
cd Downloads 
sudo dpkg -i radiotray_0.6.4_all.deb
```

then start the application:

```
nohup radiotray &
```

this will display the choice screen:

[image]

Click OK for Natty (or change the option).

Radiotray should appear in the app-indicators area of Natty.

To get Radiotray starting automatically - open Natty dash and search for `startup application`.  You can then add a new entry with the command line `radiotray`

Answer (score 5):

Well I donot know if this will work for radio tray but it is working for covergloobus and gnote in my case. To add custom notification tray in unity

First do :

`gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist`

to see the systray whitelist.

then append

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['your settings here', 'radiotray']"
```

EDIT: [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-enable-ubuntu-appindicator-for.html) explains your need

Comment: I don't think `radiotray` is the right id for this applet, or at least it doesn't work for me.

Comment: May be you try `RadioTray`. Or I have edited to add a link for webupd8 where I think it's the same thing that fossfreedom explains

Comment: This does work for me in Ubuntu 12.04 with radiotray 0.7.2. radiotray was missing in this whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed this program in Ubuntu 12.04. Ran it first time OK then it refused to open again. The initial startup script gives the option to enable the "Gnome Media Keys" plugin. I had enabled this option and it seems that this is what prevented the application from starting again.

The solution was to remove the Gnome Media Keys section from the active plugins line in the config.xml file. Works fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not support gnome-applets, and most applications will not work in the system tray (notification area) unless they are ported to indicator applets, so it is unlikely that radiotray will work in this situation.

Comment: Tray icons still work in a transition period, they just need to be whitelisted.

Comment: @Egil: I know but not all icons are working if you whitelist them (in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

This website shows you how.
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-enable-ubuntu-appindicator-for.html

Comment: -1 for only providing a link. The best practice to write instructions in your own words and attribute the source, including a link.

Answer (score 0):

Although radiotray now has application indicator support the default setting is set to "false" when it should be set to "true". You will find the configuration file in the home folder at /.local/share/radiotray/config.xml. You will need to set file manager to show hidden files in order to see the .local folder. The dot ( . ) makes the file hidden from normal file manager use.

These are the lines to change:

Change false to true. While you are there change the default sleep_timer value from 15 to 60 or 120 otherwise radiotray will stop working after 15 minutes. And you will find that you cannot reset it unless you reboot.

This is the command to put in a terminal to both load gedit and the document config.xml. You need to use sudo to let you save the changes.

gksudo gedit ~/.local/share/radiotray/config.xml

Did is what I had to do to get radiotray working under Unity just a few days ago.

Regards.